# How can I input something in a label

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I'm working on a program that it can change from degree to radian or from radian to degree ... but I can't order from the user to put his angle ... I don't know why ... and if I put just input on any line the program doesn't open or it open but when I press at any button it doesn't respond ... so can someone help me please

Note : I need help in a steps or change in the code and give me it then explain to me what you did and thank you :)

This is the code ... it will stop if you press at a button ... I want to order from the user in 46 and 54 line but this didn't work

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

label1 = Label(window, relief='groove', width=25)
label2 = Label(window, relief='groove', width=2)
label3 = Label(window, relief='groove', width=8)


FirBtn = Button(window)
SecBtn = Button(window)


label1.grid()
label2.grid()
label3.grid()

FirBtn.grid()
SecBtn.grid()


label1.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10)
label2.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10)
label3.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=10)

FirBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=5)
SecBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=5)


window.title("My Program")


window.resizable(0, 0)


label1.configure(text="What is the value of your angle : ")
label2.configure(text="...")
label3.configure(text="...")

FirBtn.configure(text="1_ Change from Degree to Radian")
SecBtn.configure(text="2_ Change from Radian to Degree")


def Degree():
    a = label2.configure(text=float(input("")))
    label3.configure(text=('a =', a / 180, 'π'))

    FirBtn.configure(state=DISABLED)
    SecBtn.configure(state=NORMAL)


def Radian():
    a = label2.configure(text=float(input("")))
    label3.configure(text=print('d =', a * 180, 'degree'))

    FirBtn.configure(state=NORMAL)
    SecBtn.configure(state=DISABLED)

FirBtn.configure(command=Degree)
SecBtn.configure(command=Radian)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In order to accept input, you probably want to use a `tk.Entry` i/o a `tk.Label`.

Comment: Nothing called tk.entry or tk.label ... please if you can solve this problem fix it from the code and send it for me and thank you